# Making three20 integration independent to machine?

Tags: iphone, three20

i just integrated the three20 framework as per as instruction provided. And its working fine. But when i sent the my project on other machine, its giving linking error. I think all the linking to be done to local to the machine. How to avoid all such scenario and how to make project independent to machine ?

so that no need to set again all the setting to that machine ?

Is something i am missing ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have three20 setup to be an external project.  This is by design so that when three20 changes, you can get the updated source easily and also so you can share three20 across different projects.

You have 2 choices here:

1. Embed three20 in your project.  To do this, you want to add the three20 project to your project, and when you do, check the "Copy resources into Project" checkbox.
2. Checkout a new version of three20 on your secondary machine

Choice 2 is recommended highly over choice 1, just make sure the directory structure is similar between the two computers so the relative search paths are the same.

Comment: Well for choice 1 : Shall i need to add all the used three20 project (Three20UI , Three20Core etc) in my project folder and add from there 
. Is that work or need to do something else ?

Comment: You have three20 setup now to just be a link to a directory on your device.  Thus, the compiler knows where to go to see the project and subprojects.  If you copy it all in (every three20 project and subproject) the compiler will know to just look in your project folder for the same files.  It will work exactly the same assuming you copy every necessary three20 file over.